# Swift Dictionary inside value access and change (dictionary involving array)

Tags: swift

My data type is dictionary which inside value are array. =
I cannot access and change value.

I tried to change something(i.e. optional binding (let), get function, !?, etc.)

```
let roadMap = [
    "home": ["hair": 5, "super": 10, "academy": 9],
    "hair": ["home": 5, "super": 3, "bank": 11],
    "superMarket":["hairShop":3, "home":10, "englishAcademy":7, "restourant":3],
    "englishAcademy": ["home":9, "superMarket":7, "school":12],
    "restourant" :      ["superMarket":3, "bank":4],
    "bank" :            ["hairShop":11, "restourant":4, "englishAcademy":7, "school":2],
    "school" :          ["bank":2, "englishAcademy":12]]

var fastWay: [String: [Any]] = [:]
    for i in roadMap.keys{
    fastWay.updateValue([0, 9999, "start"], forKey: i)}

var nextPlace = "noWay"
var min = 8888

for i in fastWay.keys {
    if fastWay[i][0] == 0 {
        fastWay[i][0] = min }}

print (fastWay)
```

Xcode playground comments: 
Value of optional type '[Any]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[Any]'

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: The compiler doesn't know if there is a value for key `i` in the dictionary.

In this case – as **you** know that all keys have values – you can force unwrap the value.

But there is another error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int'

This error is clear, too: To compare an `Any?` value with an `Int` you have to conditional downcast it.

```
for i in fastWay.keys {
    if fastWay[i]![0] as? Int == 0 {
        fastWay[i]![0] = min
    }
}
```

If it's not guaranteed that there is a value for a key you have to use optional chaining to make (yourself and) the compiler happy, for example

```
if fastWay["foo"]?[0] as? Int == 0 { ...
```